# Fabric DetailsList change child row controls based on parent row

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-fabric

I've a details list as shown below.

```
<DetailsList
                        selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={false}
                        items={projectData}
                        columns={getGridColumns()}
                        setKey="set"
                        layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
                        isHeaderVisible={true}
                        selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}                       
                    >
                    </DetailsList>
```

My question is about a column *Executed* which renders a *Toggle* as shown below.

```
{
                key: "executed",
                maxWidth: 80,
                minWidth: 10,
                name: "Executed YES/NO?",
                isResizable: true,
                isCollapsible: true,
                data: 'string',
                onRender: (item: IProjectTask) => {
                    return <Toggle onText="On", OffText="Off" />
                }
            }
```

Upon rendering it displays as shown below. This DetailsList is bound to an array, as you can see
*project 0* is the parent of *project1* and *project2*

[image]

My questions is : When I change the *Executed* toggle button on a parent row, the child rows *Executed* should automatically be checked and disabled. in short I want to control child rows toggle button behavior from parent row toggle button. please help.

Answer (score 0):

After I understood the state mechanism in detail, the problem got solved.